# Low-rank approximation and computational cost for a matrix-vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I think I am missing the point of the low-rank approximation.

For $\textbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ the matrix - vector product has computational cost $cN^2$ for $c$ constant.

By applying the low-rank approximation method we construct matrices $\textbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, $\textbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ with $k \ll n$ such that $\textbf{A} \approx \textbf{BC}$. How does that lower the computational cost of the matrix-vector product, i.e $\textbf{A}x \approx \textbf{BC} x$? From my calculations the cost is $kN^2$.

Comment: k might be much less than c

Comment: You can first compute $y=Cx$, which takes $O(kn)$ time and then you calculate $By$, which again takes $O(nk)$ time. So the overall runtime is $O(nk)$, which is much smaller than $O(n^2)$ if $k\ll n$.

Comment: @user58955  Thanks, I have miscalculated the overall cost! The overall cost is indeed O(nk).